# Is windows cmd will filter some special symbols?

Tags: go

I tried to resolve command line arguments that may be a string with some special symbols, such as `-i github.com/jquery/jquery^2.2.3`, but os.Args got the no `^` string, I don't known why process filter this symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have a Windows machine but it works in linux shell. Also you can check this one `-i "github.com/jquery/jquery^2.2.3"`